# Are there scenes missing from the home versions related to Marie Kreutz?

Tags: alternate-version, the-bourne-identity

Two of us watched the Bourne Identity at the cinema when it was released and later watched the same film on a VHS or DVD version (can't remember which).

We were both surprised to find scenes we both remembered from the cinema version missing from the home release. These relate to the background of Marie Kreutz. Specifically that she had bombed a building she thought had been empty.

I was surprised to find absolutley nothing about any of this online, leading us to suspect we may have both got confused and misremembered something.

Does anyone know if these scenes exist and anything about them if so? Alternatively if they don't, any theories as to where our confusion may have arisen from?

Comment: i don't remember any real background on her at all other than her brother thinking she's trouble...

Comment: I can't even imagine that background fitting to her character at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scene you are thinking of is from the movie *Spy Games* with Robert Redford and Brad Pitt. Pitt is an undercover CIA contractor working for Redford and meets this girl who he hopes can get him closer to a doctor. He finds out from Redford that she is not allowed back into Britain because she bombed a building owned by China that was supposed to be empty but wasn't, killing many people.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to say *you and your friend remembered this from something else*.

In none of the Bourne releases does the scene you mention seem to exist. I found a [great review](http://thesmartmarks.com/printer_684.shtml) detailing what was on the Bourne Identity DVD release, including deleted scenes, and it's certainly not mentioned there.

[Cinema Blend](http://www.cinemablend.com/dvds/The-Bourne-Identity-Explosive-Extended-Edition-573.html) cover what was released on the "Extended Edition" discs and again, there's no added or removed scenes to explain what you saw.

So, I'm going to say **the scenes don't exist and were remembered from elsewhere**.

As to where that particular memory comes from - I have no idea I'm afraid. It's a little too vague to be able to pinpoint a specific film from it.